# Play audio in editor with a start time

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

Hello I am trying to play audio in a custom editor and set the start sample time.

```
public static void PlayClip(AudioClip clip, int startSample = 0, bool loop = false)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly unityEditorAssembly = typeof(AudioImporter).Assembly;
    System.Type audioUtilClass = unityEditorAssembly.GetType("UnityEditor.AudioUtil");
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = audioUtilClass.GetMethod(
        "PlayClip",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        new System.Type[] { typeof(AudioClip), typeof(int), typeof(bool) },
        null
    );
    method.Invoke(
        null,
        new object[] { clip, startSample, loop }
    );
}
```

If anyone knows how to do it please help me :)

Comment: Presumably your current code isn't working? What happens?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Yeah :) Everything works except the startSample...no matter what the value is, the song will always start at the beginning. I found more people on some forums with the same problem and the same code but only one seems that knew the solution but I can't understand it  https://answers.unity.com/questions/844896/how-to-play-audioclip-from-editor-from-a-start-sam.html?childToView=1680592#comment-1680592

Comment: @PhilippLenssen If you know how to solve this please, please help me. I am working an editor extension and I really need this feature. If I can't find a solution I will have to change a lot of code and use the extension in play mode. If you could help me it will mean a lot to me :)